# Turning a list comprehension into a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, range

I ma trying to tunr the list comprehension codes `trow=[left+right for left,right in zip(trow+y, y+trow)]` into a for loop instead of a list comprehension. I have attempted to do this conversion but it does not work. How  will I be able to do this?

For loop Code:

```
def PascalTriangle(n):
   trow = [1]
   y = [0]
   for x in range(n):
      print(trow)
      for left,right in zip(trow+y, y+trow):
        trow.append(left+right)
   return n>=1

PascalTriangle(6)
```

List comprehension Code:

```
def PascalTriangle(n):
   trow = [1]
   y = [0]
   for x in range(n):
      print(trow)
      trow=[left+right for left,right in zip(trow+y, y+trow)]
   return n>=1

PascalTriangle(6)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 4, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 11, 5, 1]
```

Expected Output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

Comment: `trow.append(left+right)` is in-place and returns `None`. Remove the assignment

Comment: I have done that but how will I append to the `trow` list

Comment: To clarify what @rdas is saying, instead of `trow = trow.append(...)` just do `trow.append(...)`.

Comment: I have updated the issue i still cant get to the expected Output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a temporary list to collect all values:

```
def PascalTriangle(n):
    trow = [1]
    y = [0]

    for x in range(n):
        print(trow)
        line = []
        for left, right in zip(trow + y, y + trow):
            line.append(left + right)
        trow = line
    return n >= 1


PascalTriangle(6)
```

Out:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```